# How to properly defined a category of functors?

Tags: category-theory, foundations

I’ve got a foundational question about category theory today :

How do we define a category of functors (and maybe for that matter how do you define a category) ?

I’ve got a problem with the definitions I’ve seen because the categories of functors where define even for non small categories. The problem here is that the morphisms between functors are natural transformations, which are, in non small categories, proper classes. This isn’t allowed in the definition of a category since the morphisms between two objects are supposed to form a set (thus the morphisms need to be sets as they are elements of a set).

How do we resolve this ?

Thanks in advance,
Max

Comment: The collection of morphisms between two objects need not be a set. The categories for which this is the case are called locally small and of course not every catgeory needs to be locally small.

Comment: @jd27 indeed, but the problem is the same. The objects and morphisms of a category are sets, and a natural transformation isn’t.

Answer (score 0):

This is mainly a fake question and you should ignore it. A category is any model of the first-order theory of categories. There’s no reason any part of that model needs to be made out of sets. Some authors insist that all categories should have sets of homs between two fixed objects, but they shouldn’t do this. It bothers and confuses people for no good reason.

Comment: Indeed, but as you stated, it’s « first order » and the natural transformations aren’t first order if we do not impose bounds on the size of the objects we consider. No ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. The morphisms of a functor category are the natural transformations between two functors; such a natural transformation is given by giving, for each object of the domain, a morphism of the codomain (satisfying a certain property.) If you want to say exactly what kind of thing the collection of all natural transformations is then you'll need to fix some foundational background conditions, but this has nothing to do with explaining what a functor category is. The definition is, in essence, parametric over your choice of foundations.

Comment: What I mean is that defining one specific natural transformation between functors is a first order logic thing, but doing it for all pair of functors isn’t. You can quantity on the pairs of functors, which aren’t first order logic structures/statements. No ?

Comment: My point is that it doesn't matter whether you have some principle allowing you to describe the collection of all natural transformations. To give a category you must give a way to determine when something is an object of that category and when something is a morphism between two objects of that category. It's irrelevant for basic purposes in what sense you allow yourself to collect all the objects, the morphisms between two fixed objects, or all the morphisms, into some kind of class.

Comment: Exactly, and you have no mean (of first order) to express/describe what a functor is nor what a natural transformation is. You can define them informally or with meta-mathematics, but you can’t express it within first order language. This blocks you from forming categories of functors in normal mathematics. If you allow higher order logics or a whole new formalization of mathematics you can, or you could also treat and prove metatheorems wich is fine, but you can’t really use common mathematics framework. No ?

Comment: Mathematics is not a formal activity. If you want to ask a question about mathematical logic, that’s really a different issue. It’s hard for me to say anything more useful without you actually explaining what you mean by words like “blocks”. Obviously there is no blockage to discussing what natural transformations are because we’ve been doing it for a day or two, with no effect of any kind from size issues.

Comment: You might find Johnstone’s discussion of size issues in the introduction to the Elephant enlightening; he’s the most rigorous of category theorists and, or perhaps thus, still has no concern at all with discussing categories of functors between arbitrary categories.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your answers. I guess this “”debate”” exists because we were considering different visions/parts of mathematics. I was on the logic/foundational part whereas I have no problem whatsoever to manipulate categories of functors intuitively. Thanks again for all your answers !!! :)